# Navigating to parent folder in angularJS URL

Tags: angularjs, maven, angular-ui-router

I am using angular's ui-router in order to switch between templates.  However, in order to access the directory that contains my templates I need to go up a couple levels in the directory structure.  I can get my project working by putting my templates them in the directory `viewTemplates` within the `static` directory because it is considering that the root directory.

But is there a way to navigate in the url so that I can put my templates in the `templates` directory located in the `resources` directory?  I'm using maven to build my project so it would make more sense for me to have my templates all in the `templates` directory instead of the one that I created.  I've also tried using `../` to try and navigate up to parent directories, but that didn't seem to work for some reason.

Here is the structure:

[image]

i'm using the `ui.router` like this:

```
 $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: '/viewTemplates/deploys.html',
            controller: 'myController'
        })
```

Comment: is deploys.html working ??

Comment: Did you try "../templates/index.html" ?

Comment: @NagaSaiA yes. deploys.html is working.  index.html is the first file. the other files are just templates.  so everything is working fine as is. but I don't know how to move all the files in viewTemplates to `templates` and still be able to access them in js file which is located in the `app` folder

Comment: /viewTemplates/deploys.html works fine , in that case no need to use ../ , you should be able to access /templates/